# c# sample code for floating license server using rhino-licensing

Tags: license-key, rhino-licensing

I am trying to develop a licensing system using Rhino-Licensing but there is practically nothing available in terms of sample code or instructions for a floating license server and corresponding code on the client side. Could anyone post some hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have taken look on Github project, its having test cases which you can take a look and implement it

https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-licensing/

Also 
http://www.jagregory.com/writings/rhino-licensing/

Comment: Thanks. These links were helpful. One issues remained, which is how to set the number of floating licenses available from the LicensingServide. Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this one helpful, check it out:

http://patrick.lioi.net/2013/01/08/whittling-rhino-licensing/